# ConditionalExpression still resulting from Assuming a Module's local variables

Tags: programming, recursion, scoping, assumptions

I have a memoizing, recursive function whose MWE looks like this (the two **fake** inputs/ICs are from 'K' and 'Bfun2', the latter just a quick way to check the results coming out of the Residue.:

```
K[z0_, z1_] := K

Bfun2[z0_, z1_, z2_, z3_] := 
  Normal[Series[1/Exp[z0*z1*z2*z3], {z0, 1, 9}]]/(z0*z1*z2*z3)^5 // 
  ExpandAll

ClearAll[wgn2g];

wgn2g[g_Integer, n_Integer, zp___List] :=
 wgn2g[g, n, zp] =
  Sum[
   Module[{z, tmp1, tmp1b, tmp2, asso, T1},
    Assuming[
     Flatten[Join[{z}, Drop[zp, -Length[zp]/2]]] \[Element] 
      Complexes,
     Which[
      g < 0, 0,
      n < 0, 0,
      2*g - 2 + n == -4, 0,
      2*g - 2 + n == -3, 0,
      2*g - 2 + n == -2, 0,
      2*g - 2 + n == -1, 0,
      2*g - 2 + n == 0, 
        Bfun2[zp[[1]], zp[[2]], zp[[3]], zp[[4]], ch],
      2*g - 2 + n >= 1,
      (
       tmp1 = Rest[Drop[zp, -Length[zp]/2]];
       tmp1b = Rest[Drop[zp, Length[zp]/2]];
       tmp2 = If[n >= 2, Complement[Subsets[tmp1, n - 2], {{}}], {}];
       asso = AssociationThread[tmp1, tmp1b];
       T1 = 
        Table[{tmp2[[o]], Complement[tmp1, tmp2[[o]]]}, {o, 1, 
          Length[tmp2]}];
       Residue[
        K[z, First[zp], j, First[Drop[zp, Length[zp]/2]], ch]
         *
         (
          wgn2g[g - 1, n + 1,
            Flatten[List[
              Join[
               {z, -z},
               Rest[Drop[zp, -Length[zp]/2]],
               {j, j},
               Rest[Drop[zp, Length[zp]/2]]
               ]
              ]]
            ]
           +
           (
            If[
             Length[T1] > 0,
             (
              Sum[
               Sum[
                (
                  wgn2g[h, 1 + Length[T1[[wc]][[1]]],
                   Flatten[List[
                    Join[
                    {z},
                    T1[[wc]][[1]],
                    {j},
                    asso /@ T1[[wc]][[1]]
                    ]
                    ]]
                   ]
                  )  
                 *
                 (
                  wgn2g[g - h, 1 + Length[T1[[wc]][[2]]],
                   Flatten[List[
                    Join[
                    {-z},
                    T1[[wc]][[2]],
                    {j},
                    asso /@ T1[[wc]][[2]]
                    ]
                    ]]
                   ]
                  )    
                , {h, 0, g}]
               , {wc, 1, Length[T1], 1}]
              ),
             0,
             Print["shouldn't be here"]
             ]
            )   
          )
        , {z, 0}]
       )
      ](*close which*)
     ]
    ]
   , {j, 1, Nbps, 1}]
```

Because every time it "recursed" it need to re-create a bunch of things, I utilized 'local variables' from the `Module[]` tool.

Before wrapping the argument of `Module[]` with `Assuming[]`, I was getting conditional expressions. **But now I still get them - the `Assuming[]` function should pass assumptions to every new local variable, right?**

For instance, with the **real input functions** (that are too long to post), I get this output;

```
-((I (-13624934400 + 1703116800 z0^4 - 149022720 z0^8 + 
        12235520 z0^12 - 1029160 z0^16 + 
        90041 z0^20) (185638837404303360000 - 
        23204854675537920000 z1^4 + 2030424784109568000 z1^8 - 
        166708157349888000 z1^12 + 14022237487104000 z1^16 - 
        1226802718310400 z1^20 - 23204854675537920000 z2^4 + 
        2900606834442240000 z1^4 z2^4 - 
        253803098013696000 z1^8 z2^4 + 20838519668736000 z1^12 z2^4 - 
        1752779685888000 z1^16 z2^4 + 153350339788800 z1^20 z2^4 + 
        2030424784109568000 z2^8 - 253803098013696000 z1^4 z2^8 + 
        22207771076198400 z1^8 z2^8 - 1823370471014400 z1^12 z2^8 + 
        153368222515200 z1^16 z2^8 - 13418154731520 z1^20 z2^8 - 
        166708157349888000 z2^12 + 20838519668736000 z1^4 z2^12 - 
        1823370471014400 z1^8 z2^12 + 149707949670400 z1^12 z2^12 - 
        12592307763200 z1^16 z2^12 + 1101698456320 z1^20 z2^12 + 
        14022237487104000 z2^16 - 1752779685888000 z1^4 z2^16 + 
        153368222515200 z1^8 z2^16 - 12592307763200 z1^12 z2^16 + 
        1059170305600 z1^16 z2^16 - 92666595560 z1^20 z2^16 - 
        1226802718310400 z2^20 + 153350339788800 z1^4 z2^20 - 
        13418154731520 z1^8 z2^20 + 1101698456320 z1^12 z2^20 - 
        92666595560 z1^16 z2^20 + 
        8107381681 z1^20 z2^20))/(1264658490862949778849792000000 \
Sqrt[2] z0^2 z1^2 z2^2)) + 
 Residue[ConditionalExpression[0, 
   Im[z$39445] == 0 && 
Re[z$39445] > 
     0 && (Im[z0] != 
       0 || (Re[z0] < 0 && Re[z0] + Re[z$39445] < 0) || (Re[z0] > 0 &&
     Re[z0] > Re[z$39445]))], {z$39445, 0}]
```

which tells me I get an additional '0' if certain conditions apply ;)

(The call is `wgn2g[g,n,{z0,z1,...,zn,i0,i1,...,in}]`, not that I think it is needed...)

However, I do get other ones that are not so simple and I wonder how I can pass additional assumptions on to the local variables to avoid this.

I know how to use `Assuming[]` and `Simplify[%,Assumptions->blah blah]`, but **is there a way to make an assumption on the current `z` wrt the previous `z`?** I've noticed that I've had to do things like this - the big problem being that the `z$####` local variables change name and are unpredictable to do ahead of time;

```
Simplify[Out[104], 
 Assumptions -> 
  Re[z$1757641/z$1961753] > 1 && Re[z$1756741/z$1961753] > 1 && 
   Re[z$1756741/z$1771944] > 1 && Re[z$1756741/z$1810064] > 1 && 
   Re[z$1756741/z$1847663] > 1 && Re[z$1756741/z$1885817] > 1 && 
   Re[z$1756741/z$1923887] > 1 && Re[z$1756741/z$1771944] > 1 && 
   Re[z$1756741/z$1847663] > 1 ]
```

For clarity, these `z's` are simply local coordinates on a Riemann surface, so I don't want to necessarily constrain them to be purely real, imaginary, whatever - like `Im[z$39445] == 0` above - but they could be of course...

Comment: `Assumptions` (whether specified in `$Assumptions` or `Assuming`) have no effect except within functions that take the option `Assumptions` (e.g., `Simplify`, `FullSimplify`, `Integrate`, `Refine`, `FunctionExpand`, `Limit`).

Comment: I cannot see how to reproduce the behavior.

Comment: well it does make sense one cannot reproduce the behavior, at afaik because I only have a model of the core recursion, without the real input functions...  I think I have a way to build assumptions of prior z's with current ones. utilizing a global variable and assuming on that...